# Figures not visible with anything other than \begin{figure}[H]

Tags: floats

I have a lot of white space in my document because I have been using `\begin{figure}[H]` with `[H]` as the placement specifier for figures.  I have been using this because all other placement specifiers (`[h]`, `[t]`, no specifier, etc.) result in no figure being displayed at all.  If I use `[H]` then I have a lot of extra white space, but if I don't use `[H]` the figure does not appear at all.  I have `\usepackage{float}` in my preamble.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) where this happens? Normally, the figures should show up somewhere whatever placement specifier is used.

Comment: If you use `[H]` from the float package, the figure will be forced at that position, no matter what. Otherwise figures that do not fit may float to the end of the document. You can resolve this by making the figures small enough to fit on a page.

Comment: H by design chooses bad page breaks and excessive white space rather than moving the figure. if the figure does not appear then you will get an error message giving the reason. but as you haven't shown example input or any errors, impossible to guess your error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal working example that reproduces the symptoms you describe. If you compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1.1\textheight}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-33]
\end{document}
```

then the figure will be at the very end. If you replace `\begin{figure}[h]` by `\begin{figure}[H]`, the figure will be on page 2. Neither of these options is really good. An arguably better solution is to make the figure small enough, e.g.

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{0.8\textheight}
\end{figure}
```

and not to use the `float` package. Please also note that you need to fix *all* figures. If all but the first one are fine, they will still all get moved to the end.

Of course, this answer entails some amount of guess work, which would not be necessary if there was an actual MWE. It is well possible that there are additional issues. However, to fix them systematically, one better has an explicit code that leads to these issues.